# Put on a Personal Improvement Plan, what to do?

Tags: manager, review

Following my last question ([Attitude to take following reported user complains](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92811/attitude-to-take-following-reported-user-complains)), 6 months have passed and I’ve done a lot to improve the situation. According. To my manager I did, but she didn’t help in any way; not even having had any improvement conversation setup with me.

The mid-year review is bad and from users only, passed down to me with no comment from my manager that doesn’t filter any. She put me off track and now putting me on a PIP.

I believe that she is covering her mistakes and inability to perform as the required standards through me. She is going down the ladders of the company and bringing me with her.

What would you do? Tempted to escalate that to her manager before we close the mid year review (today) - though her manager is quite on her side some not knowing my side of things.
Should I go to the HR team?

Comment: There is too little information for a really definitive answer. However a PIP is a very major step before firing which would seem very likely. Pointless to escalate since 2nd level and HR probably had so sign off on PIP. The PIP is to protect company from being sued after they fire you, not a real attempt to retrain you. Start looking for a new job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HR is not your friend here. I'm not trying to be harsh but I assume from this and the previous question that they can indeed rustle up some "user complaints" to "justify" the PIP if they needed to. I don't mean to imply that you are bad at your job here - just that *anyone* in a customer facing role is going to encounter negative feedback from customers in one form or another and for whatever reason your manager appears to have chosen to hang you out to dry.

If (as you say) your manager's boss is on good terms with her and will accept your manager's version of events then that's a dead end as well.

Honestly I don't think the situation at this employer is going to be salvagable for you - PIP's are often seen as step 1 of the firing process, and in any event are generally very difficult to recover from. And without a supportive manager I'd say your odds of surviving the PIP drop to near zero.

I think Snark Shark nailed it - now is the time to be polishing the resume and getting on the job hunt. Obviously keeping your head down and complying with the PIP-conditions at your current place in order to keep that valuable "employed" status as long as you can.

Comment: All, thank you really much for all your feedbacks, although harsh it’s definitely good to read and understand the situation. Got some meeting with my manager’s manager all together and got asked to get me out of the PIp. Manager still wants to, seems really personal...

Answer (score 2):

Start looking for another job right now, but adhere to the terms of your PIP plan in the meantime.

It does sounds as though things have gone sour in your current workplace, so you really need to start from fresh someplace else.